# Can't change default download directory for Remote Chrome in Ruby + Webdriver

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, webdriver

I want to use Chrome in my Test on Webdriver + Ruby to download files on remote computers. 
On my developer computer everything works fine with this code:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = Settings::DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY
@@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :profile => profile
```

But I want to use run code on several remote machines and use this code

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = "/mnt/samba/share_location/"
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:profile => profile)
@@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://" +remote_server + ":4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Second variant didn't working, browser download file to default download loaction on each remote computer

Please, help me to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is unfortunately not very intuitive. I'll try to improve it for future versions. Here's a workaround for now:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = "/mnt/samba/share_location/"

data = profile.as_json

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
caps['chromeOptions'] = {
  'profile'    => data['zip'],
  'extensions' => data['extensions']
}

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :desired_capabilities => caps
```

Comment: Thanks, it work. Do you developer of WebDriver. You said you'll try to improve it

Comment: hey, how can i do the same in java?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest versions of WebDriver.

Comment: Always getting an error like "Failed to open TCP Connection to 127.0.0.1:4444"